# Google Maps markers not shown in Android WebView loading local file

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, google-maps-markers

I'm figuring out how to render markers on a **Google Map** in a html local page in Android **WebView**. If the WebView url is remote, the markers are correctly shown. When loading the local file, instead, only the map is rendered.

Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Any update for this?